# Looping through Dictionary of Unicode Data

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to loop through a list of unicode data. `type(d['results'])` is a `list`.  However, `organization_fields` is actually a `dict` but formatted as unicode when looking at the load.  The question is, how can I access `organization_fields`? I've tried to change the format using `ast.literal_eval(k)` but have had some errors in trying to do so.

Also, I'm getting my response `r` and saving it as `d = r.json()`

I have

```
       for a in d['results']:
 ...:     for k,v in a.iteritems():
 ...:         print k
 ...:         print type(k)  
 ...:         print('------break-----')
```

Here is the output:

```
 name
 <type 'unicode'>
 ------break-----
 shared_comments
 <type 'unicode'>
 ------break-----
 url
 <type 'unicode'>
 ------break-----
 organization_fields
<type 'unicode'>
------break-----
```

`organization_fields`

```
    u'organization_fields': {
       u'account_type': None, 
       u'id':  u'some_id', 
       u'value': None
  },
```

**UPDATE**

When i try printing `d['results'][0]` I do get a list of items that are in here Ex. `url`, `name`, except `organization_fields` does not exist in it.  It only exists when i loop through `a` in the above `for` loop

Comment: Add the results of `print d` to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

organization_fields is not stored as unicode. The key is a unicode string, but the type of the value stored by the key u'organization_fields' is a dictionary of more values stored with unicode string keys. Accessing values of organization fields is identical to accessing values of any other dictionary.

If you want to access organization_fields in your for loop:

```
for a in d['results']:
    org_fields = a['organization_fields']
    print org_fields
```

Edit: It does not sound like every element of d['results'] contains a dictionary with a value stored by the key organization_fields. This should do the trick.

```
for a in d['results']:
    if 'organization_fields' in a:
        org_fields = a['organization_fields']
        print org_fields
```

If you want to see which index of d['results'] contains the value of organization_fields, then do this:

```
for i, a in enumerate(d['results']):
    if 'organization_fields' in a:
        org_fields = a['organization_fields']
        print org_fields
        print 'index: %s' % i
```

Then, with the index you printed from there, you can access it directly:

```
org_fields = d['results'][index printed]['organization_fields']
```

Comment: Received: `KeyError: 'organization_fields'`

Comment: @Rem My edits should give you a clear path to solving your problem. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question...

But if I did, you should try something like :

```
print d['result'][0]['organization_fields']['id']
```

which should print

```
some_id
```

--> I don't think there's any "unicode data" : there are dictionnaries with unicode strings as keys.

Comment: I'm trying to access the `organization_fields` dictionary but it is stored as unicode.  I just tried that and got `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` -- I'm wondering is there a way to turn it into a dictionary, not unicode data?

Comment: Yep, I missed that there is a list within your stack of data. I added a [0] into my post.